# Can we share logs to server without notifying to user in iOS Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging

We are saving the log statement in log file. We want to access log file from app without notifying the user.
Can we share logs to server without notifying to user in iOS Application?

Comment: You better be very careful. In many places this would be illegal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just send the log file to your server in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you creating file programmatically, You can always  access that without notifying user about that.

You can access and send file on server through webservices.